# In a unit test, do you verify and assert?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I am using Moq in my unit test project. Most unit test examples I've seen online end with `someMock.VerifyAll();`  I wonder if it is OK to assert after `VerifyAll()`.  So for example,

```cs
//Arrange
var student = new Student{Id = 0, Name="John Doe", IsRegistered = false};
var studentRepository = new Mock<IStudentRepository>();
var studentService= new StudentService(studentRepository.Object);

//Act
studentService.Register(student);  //<-- student.IsRegistered = true now.

//Verify and assert
studentRepository.VerifyAll();
Assert.IsTrue(student.IsRegistered);
```

Any thought? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you should call the assert.

`VerifyAll()` will assert that all `SetUp()` calls were actually called.

`VerifyAll()` will not confirm that your student object is registered. Because there are no `SetUp()` calls in your test case, I think `VerifyAll()` isn't verifying anything.

Comment: Thank you. I was just wondering if verify (all) and assert side by side is considered best practice. Thanks. Yeah, verify and assert really serve two different kinds of purposes. I think.

Answer (score 29):

**No you should not use both together** in most cases(there are always exceptions). The reason for that is you should be testing only one thing in your test for maintainability, readability and few other reasons. So it should be either Verify(VerifyAll) or Assert in your test and you name your tests accordingly.

Look at Roy Osherove's article about it:

http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/a-unit-test-should-test-only-one-thing.html

`VerifyAll` is used to make sure certain methods are called and how many times. You use `mocks` for that.

`Assert` is used for verifying the result returned from the method you are testing. You use `Stubs` for that.

Martin fowler has a great article explaining the difference between mocks and stubs. If you understand it you will know the difference better.

http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

UPDATE: example of mock vs stub using Moq as requested in the comment below. I have used Verify but you can use VerifyAll as well.

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;
... 

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Test using Mock to Verify that GetNameWithPrefix method calls 
    /// Repository GetName method once when Id is greater than Zero
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetNameWithPrefix_IdIsTwelve_GetNameCalledOnce()
    {
        // Arrange 
        var mockEntityRepository = new Mock<IEntityRepository>();
        mockEntityRepository.Setup(m => m.GetName(It.IsAny<int>()));

        var entity = new EntityClass(mockEntityRepository.Object);
        // Act 
        var name = entity.GetNameWithPrefix(12);
        // Assert
        mockEntityRepository.Verify(
            m => m.GetName(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Once);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Test using Mock to Verify that GetNameWithPrefix method 
    /// doesn't calls Repository GetName method when Id is Zero
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetNameWithPrefix_IdIsZero_GetNameNeverCalled()
    {
        // Arrange 
        var mockEntityRepository = new Mock<IEntityRepository>();
        mockEntityRepository.Setup(m => m.GetName(It.IsAny<int>()));
        var entity = new EntityClass(mockEntityRepository.Object);
        // Act 
        var name = entity.GetNameWithPrefix(0);
        // Assert
        mockEntityRepository.Verify(
            m => m.GetName(It.IsAny<int>()), Times.Never);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Test using Stub to Verify that GetNameWithPrefix method
    /// returns Name with a Prefix
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetNameWithPrefix_IdIsTwelve_ReturnsNameWithPrefix()
    {
        // Arrange 
        var stubEntityRepository = new Mock<IEntityRepository>();
        stubEntityRepository.Setup(m => m.GetName(It.IsAny<int>()))
            .Returns("Stub");
        const string EXPECTED_NAME_WITH_PREFIX = "Mr. Stub";
        var entity = new EntityClass(stubEntityRepository.Object);
        // Act 
        var name = entity.GetNameWithPrefix(12);
        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(EXPECTED_NAME_WITH_PREFIX, name);
    }
}

public class EntityClass
{
    private IEntityRepository _entityRepository;
    public EntityClass(IEntityRepository entityRepository)
    {
        this._entityRepository = entityRepository;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GetNameWithPrefix(int id)
    {
        string name = string.Empty;
        if (id > 0)
        {
            name = this._entityRepository.GetName(id);
        }
        return "Mr. " + name;
    }
}

public interface IEntityRepository
{
    string GetName(int id);
}

public class EntityRepository:IEntityRepository
{
    public string GetName(int id)
    {
        // Code to connect to DB and get name based on Id
        return "NameFromDb";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will definitely check it out. I've been using mock a lot these days, so I have a much better understanding of it now than before. I've never used stub. I have read about it, and to my understanding it is a substitute implementation of some functionality (mostly a dependency) one needs to pass the unit test.

Comment: Lot of times developers don't understand the difference and think they are using mock but they actually use stub. You are stubbing the repository method above. It's just that you are getting default value for the repository method call as you didn't specify anything. Don't confuse it with Mock in Moq framework. You can use it for both mocking and stubbing.

Comment: So, it looks like my understanding of mock isn't correct. Do you have an example that demonstrates the differences between mock and stub using Moq and C#? That'll also help a lot of other newbies of unit tests. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. You can even copy that code and run it in a unit test file in visual studio. You will have to add a reference to Moq Nuget package

Comment: I updated it again to answer your main question about using Assert and VerifyAll together. Hope it helps.

Comment: As I read and test, it still seems to me that when we use Verify or VerifyAll, we are doing that on mocks instead of stubs. In other words, the mocks in my initial code sample are really mocks instead of stubs. What do you think?  I have read here at SO that Moq framework intentionally blurred the distinction between mocks and stubs. I will post the URL when I dig it out.

Comment: If the method under test changes the state of the object, I think it is logical and makes sense to Assert after verify.  However, there are situations where Assert after Verify isn't necessary. For example: var student = new Student{Id = 1, IsRegistered = true, Name = "John"}; var studentRepository = new Mock<IStudentRepository>(); studentRepository.Setup(f=>f.GetRegisteredStudentById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(student); var studentService = new StudentService(studentRepository.Object); var result = studentService.GetRegisteredStudentById(1); studentRepository.VerifyAll();

Comment: In the above example, we are telling the repository to return the object student we just created and set IsRegistered to true. So, it makes no sense, I think, to Assert.IsTrue(student.IsRegistered); Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to decide what you are testing when you write a test method. Are you testing whether a certain method is called within that or you are testing the output? That's how you name your test as well. If you are testing 2 different things create separate test methods. http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html

Comment: Well, look at the initial code sample I have. The Register method changes the state of the student object. So, I think the Assert there totally makes sense.  I do understand the general practice of testing only one thing per unit test. If we do this with my initial code sample, we will have two unit tests which are identical except the last line, where in one unit test, the last line is studentRepository.VerifyAll() and in the other it is Assert.IsTrue(student.IsRegistered).  Is it really necessary to split into two unit tests in this case?

Comment: It depends. If you are just setting the IsRegistered to true based on a successful return of the object from repository then I don't think so. But if you have any logic based on which you set it then yes.

Comment: I'm not saying you don't need Assert but do it in separate test method. To your question about absolutely necessary it's just a good practice. You might have exceptions but this doesn't look like exception to me. If you start naming methods the way Roy suggests you will automatically have only the verification/assertion specified in the name.

Comment: Check out this question for making convention: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874768/how-do-you-name-your-unit-test-methods

Comment: Minor point, the setups in your first 2 tests are unnecessary and IMO just pollute the test. Even more minor point, there should be another test which verifies that the id is actually passed to the repository.

Answer (score 7):

I would absolutely expect to see `Verify` and `Assert` used side-by-side within a unit test. Asserts are used to validate that properties of your system under test have been set correctly, whereas `Verify` is used to ensure that any dependencies that your system under test takes in have been called correctly. When using `Moq` I tend to err on the side of explicitly verifying a setup rather than using the `VerifyAll` catch-all. That way you can make the intent of the test much clearer.

I'm assuming in the code above that your call to the student repository returns a boolean to state that the student is registered? And you then set that value on the `student` object? In that case, there is a valuable setup that needs to be added, in which you are effectively saying that when the student repository method is called, it will return true. Then you `Assert` that `student.IsRegistered` is true to ensure that you have set the property correctly from the repository return value and you `Verify` that the repository method is called with the inputs that you are expecting.

Comment: The code sample is just something I came up with while writing up the initial question. My assumption is that the IsRegistered property will be set by either the StudentService or any method the StudentService calls. In any case, after the Register method call, the student's IsRegistered property value is equal to true.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing intrinsically wrong with both asserting and verifying in a mocking test, though assertions that depend on the actual methods being called are likely to fail, because the mock methods do not have the same effects as the real methods.

In your example it is probably fine, as only the repository is mocked, and the change of the student state is presumably done in the service.

Whether both verify and assert should be done in the same test is to a degree a matter of taste.  Really the verify is checking that the proper calls to the repository are made, and the assert is checking that the proper change to the entity is made.  As these are separate concerns, I'd put them in separate tests, but that may just be me.

Comment: Good point. Thank you. But if you have one unit test which does VerifyAll and another which does Assert for the same method-under-test, aren't you repeating a lot of code?

Comment: It depends how you structure your tests. If you follow a BDD-style syntax, you can create tests consisting of a single Assert.

Comment: Even without BDD-style syntax, you can refactor test code to eliminate duplication just as you can refactor production code.  BDD-style is nice though!