# How do you name your unit test methods?

Tags: unit-testing

What is your general rule in naming your unit test methods? I am sure a lot of people out there also wonder about this question. Suppose, a method under test is

```
public Customer GetCustomerById(int id)
```

How would you name your unit test methods?

`GetCustomerById`?
`GetCustomerByIdTest`?
`GetCustomerByIdShouldReturnCustomer`?
`GetCustomerByIdShoudReturnCustomerWhenItSucceeds`?
`GetCustomerByIdShouldReturnNullWhenNotFound`?
`Get_Customer_By_Id`?

..and so on and so forth.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to use following format. This helps to know what exactly you are testing by just looking at the test method name.

```
[UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior]

GetCustomerById_WithValidId_ReturnsCustomer
GetCustomerById_WithInvalidId_ReturnsNull
```

This is using Roy Oshrove's suggested naming standard:
http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/naming-standards-for-unit-tests.html

Comment: That's great. Thanks. This implies that more unit test methods are needed for this GetCustomerById method. Such as GetCustomerById_WithInvalidId_ShouldReturnNull or maybe GetCustomerById_WithNegativeId_ShouldThrowInvalidCustomerIdException. Correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Each test method should test only one thing. It helps with maintenance and readability. http://osherove.com/blog/2005/4/3/a-unit-test-should-test-only-one-thing.html

Comment: That article of Roy is a nice one. Thanks for the link.

Comment: You can also read his book if you are interested. Good one. http://artofunittesting.com/

Comment: I have that book under my pillow.

Comment: I have read that article of Roy. Very helpful, but how would I name my unit test of my service method GetCustomers which calls customerRepository.GetAll()?  GetCustomers_ShouldReturnAllCustomers?

Comment: Or GetCustomers_ShouldCallGetAllOfTheCustomerRepository?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to test here. If you are just testing whether it calls the repository method then something like: GetCustomers_WithValidRepository_CallsGetAllMethodInCustomerRepository

Comment: A lot of my unit tests are behavioral tests only. I have been googling just to see if there are such unit test methods out there, but didn't find any, so I wasn't sure. But your tip helps. Thanks.